# I tried to create higher or lower Guessing game in androd studio and when i try to run it the only random number that is being generated is zero

Tags: java, android, android-studio-3.0

Here is the code used for generation of random number

```
package com.example.sastr.guessnumber;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.util.Random;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    int randomNumber;
    public void generateRandomNumber(){
        Random rand = new Random();
        int random_integer = rand.nextInt(20-1) + 1;
    }
    public void guess(View view){
        EditText editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText);
        Log.i("Random number is: ",Integer.toString(randomNumber));
        int guessnumber = Integer.parseInt(editText.getText().toString());
        String message;
        if (guessnumber > randomNumber)
        {
            message = "Number entered is greater, enter smaller number";
        }
        else if (guessnumber < randomNumber)
        {
            message = "Number entered is lower, enter bigger number";
        }
        else
        {
            message = "You guessed it right!";
            generateRandomNumber();
        }
        Toast.makeText(this,message,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Random rand = new Random();
        int random_integer = rand.nextInt(20) + 1;
    }
}
```

I have been executing the program in my phone and everytime the generated random is zero only. Can someone tell me where the problem is arising? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

You have `int randomNumber` as class field and you have a `int random_integer` in your onCreate method. I think you want to set randomNumber in your `onCreate` and your `generateRandomNumber` method.

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Random rand = new Random();
    // this is useless
    // int random_integer = rand.nextInt(20) + 1;
    // try this
    randomNumber = rand.nextInt(20-1) + 1;

    // or just called the private method generateRandomNumber you created.
    // generateRandomNumber();
    // in generateRandoNumber(); you also need to change the line to randomNumber = rand.nextInt(20-1) + 1;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You have created the variable randomNumber and never assigned the value to it. Change your generateRandomNumber() as below:

```
public void generateRandomNumber(){
    Random rand = new Random();
    randomNumber = rand.nextInt(20-1) + 1;
}
```

and change your onCreate to:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Random rand = new Random();
    randomNumber = rand.nextInt(20) + 1;
}
```